# MySQL Update & Case Statements Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to run a mass UPDATE to a table altering two columns with several values.

```
UPDATE ofertanti SET
 Lat = Case OfertantId
 WHEN 1 THEN '44.4498109'
 WHEN 2 THEN '44.461097'
 WHEN 3 THEN '44.424998'
 WHEN 4 THEN '44.467109'
 WHEN 166 THEN '46.360884'
 WHEN 5 THEN '44.452551'
 WHEN 6 THEN '44.4535468'
 WHEN 7 THEN '44.437809'
 WHEN 8 THEN '44.442972'
 WHEN 10 THEN '44.4099361'
 END, 
 Long = Case OfertantId
 WHEN 1 THEN '26.099139'
 WHEN 2 THEN '26.085677'
 WHEN 3 THEN '26.075464'
 WHEN 4 THEN '26.087947'
 WHEN 166 THEN ' 25.803683'
 WHEN 5 THEN '26.078921'
 WHEN 6 THEN '26.0887823'
 WHEN 7 THEN '26.1158709'
 WHEN 8 THEN '26.131282'
 WHEN 10 THEN '26.0705676'
END
```

It throws me this error:

```
Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long = Case OfertantId WHEN 1 THEN '26.099139' WHEN 2 THEN '26.085677' WHEN 3' at line 14
```

Any idea what have I done wrong? I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was caused by `Long`, it is a reserved keyword in SQL and I was using it for longitude.